Bibcite references from migration shows HTML tags in abstracts and notes, how to strip them?
After a migration using the bibcite_migrate module, I retrieved my 2700+ references from a D7 site and the Bibliography module.
Unfortunately, HTML tags are visible on all abstracts and notes and they are not formatted.
I tried to manage the default display and table mode but I can only choose "Default" or "Trimmed" and the html tags are still visible.
When trying to display my references with Views, it's the same thing, I can't choose a text format that will decode the HTML tags (even with rewrite results and strip HTML tags options).
In the bibcite_reference table, all values contain HTML tags. I have tried to add "basic_html" for one reference (column bibcite_abst_e__format) but I see no changes.
How can I decode these HTML tags to cleanly display my abstracts and reference notes?
Thanks for any tip here.

What does “abstracts and notes have retrieved the HTML tags and nothing is decoded” mean? Be specific and add the information to the Question.

I have edited the question, let me know if screenshots can help
